# Quadcopter getting hot after a flight

Tags: quadcopters

I have a small quadcopter and after around a 10 minute flight, I can feel it gets very hot. Is this normal?

Comment: What on the quadcopter gets hot?  Motors, ESCs, VTX, FC?

Comment: @Schome1 Mainly motors and ESCs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Hot quadcopter" is a bit broad of a term, a lot of things can be hot in there.

- Maybe it's the VTX, then it's [normal](https://www.reddit.com/r/Multicopter/comments/6oiszy/vtx_gets_really_hot_this_normal/), they can get hot up to 80C. You might want to use a heatsink though, depends on your VTX.
- It might be the Flight Controller's CPU itself. For example, F7 processors can get hot up to [70C](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3148399-Kakute-F7-gets-very-hot-on-bench-(70-C))
- It also might be motors. If you can barely touch them then:

  - You might have a bad tuning on your quad:

    - High D gain
    - Not enough filtering
  - Conductivity problem, you might have too long motor screws and they are touching the windings.

---

Sources and additional info on hot motors:
https://oscarliang.com/check-motor-screws-touching-winding/
https://oscarliang.com/mini-quad-motors-overheat/
https://youtu.be/eo2sjTNS0pc

Answer (score 3):

It is normal for a drone to get hot after a flight, especially the motors as they spin up to a few hundred times per second. If the drone becomes so hot that you can barely touch it, that could be a sign of an overheating motor and you may have to replace your motor.

Comment: Hot motors can be a sign of a bad tuning also. Like high D gain or not enough filtering. https://oscarliang.com/mini-quad-motors-overheat/

Comment: @NikitaPedorich mind posting that as an answer?